# Windows 10 MediaCreationTool USB won't boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, partitioning

I used the MediaCreationTool from Microsoft to make my SanDisk 32GB Usb Stick bootable for the installation. I have a new PC with an empty HDD and want to Windows 10 on it.

When I boot and go into the BIOS, I can see 2 things - 
UEFI: SanDisk Partition 1
USB: SanDisk

Whatever I try booting from fails, the first option brings me back to the Boot Menu, the second one greets me with a black screen and the text:
"An operating system hasn't been found.."

Now, the idea I currently have is to use Rufus to put Windows 10 on the USB. What should I use though as the Rufus settings?

GPT/MBR?
Fat32/NTFS?

As well as the other settings for rufus...

The board in question is an ASRock B450 Fatality K4.

Thanks in advance and any help is welcome!

Comment: Usually, you don't have to make any adjustments with the settings, just setting the correct device and .iso with Rufus should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

gpt/mbr?
Use MBR
Fat32/NTFS?
Use FAT32(default)

Make sure you selected the usb device and the iso file and start.
It will work just fine.
You may need to change your bios settings to select boot order.Move usb boot to top.

hope this helps.Will be happy to clear any doubts.